# Can you put transformers in series to get higher voltage?

Tags: transformer

I was looking for the answer and found this related question: [Wiring transformer output in series to get twice the voltage possible?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12487/wiring-transformer-output-in-series-to-get-twice-the-voltage-possible?newreg=5edb09098df1429aa91fc8b0b3f43fcd)
But the answers don't seem to address what I was imagining. I am thinking of connecting the secondary coil of one transformer to the primary coil of the next, but the only information I can find talks about hooking the secondary of both together either in parallel or series. Am I making any sense?[image]

Answer (score 3):

You may chain two transformers, and if both have a 1:10 ratio, then the combination has a 1:100 ratio.

But beware that each transformer winding has a maximum voltage that it can withstand. If you exceed it (too much), you will experience an electric breakdown that will destroy your transformer.

For example, you cannot use a 220V-12V transformer, with the 12V winding connected to 220V mains, to produce 4kV.

Answer (score 1):

Transformers have a maximum voltage that they can output before they suffer internal breakdown, adding a second transformer before the second one does not increase this maximum voltage but it does increase the primary-to-secondary insulation (there are not many applications where this is needed). Transformers that are not designed for HV generally have much lower breakdown limits that make them unusable much beyond their designed range.

It will reduce the power that you can draw from it, I'm not sure how much by though, it is better to just use a single HV transformer and if that isn't enough then add a ladder of voltage doublers.

Answer (score 0):

If the primary of the second transformer is rated for the secondary voltage of the first transformer, there is no problem with connecting them together. The problem is that a transformer that has a primary winding rated for a voltages that is significantly higher than mains voltage and a secondary rated for a significantly higher voltage that that is usually available only for a power transmission line power level.

A transformer's voltage rating can not be exceeded by more that 10 of 15 percent without overheating due to magnetic saturation and the resulting increase in magnetizing current. Insulation breakdown voltages generally have a higher safety margin that that. So the problem will be saturation, not breakdown.